# What is the difference between qualifiers and specifiers in C?

Tags: c, qualifiers

Could some one explain what is the difference between qualifiers and specifiers in C?

Comment: http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/ANSI-C-grammar-y.html#specifier-qualifier-list

Comment: @MarcB: Not a dup of that. "modifier" is just some book author's poor imprecise language. "Specifier" and "qualifier" have formal meanings in the language.

Comment: @MarcB; Don't you think *modifier* and *specifier* both are different things?

Comment: @haccks Read the Standard (C11) 6.7.2 Type specifiers and 6.7.3 Type qualifiers

Comment: Hmmm, I don't think this is a dup, although someone in the comment of the dup linked explains what both are, it is not an answer and the difference was not asked in the question, so this is broad although simple question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about types, then this is simply a lookup in the C standard.

C99 section 6.7.2:

> *type-specifier:*
>
> ```
> void
> char
> short
> int
> ...
> ```

C99 section 6.7.3:

> *type-qualifier:*
>
> ```
> const
> restrict
> volatile
> ```

I imagine that it's clear that these are distinct categories of things...

Comment: Does both of them comes under **declaration specifier**?

Comment: @haccks: Yes.  But you could really discover this all for yourself by simply opening the language standard and doing a search...

Answer (score 5):

**Qualifiers**
The keywords which are used to modify the property of a variable are called type qualifiers

eg.

```
 const
 volatile
```

**Storage class specifiers** in C language tells the compiler where to store a variable, how to store the variable, what is the initial value of the variable and life time of the variable.

eg.

```
auto
static
int
register
```

You can learn more here [link](http://www.bezem.de/pdf/tqinc.pdf)

Comment: @dwo thanks for the edit, i will take care next time :-)